# Not able to use HTTP Basic Auth popup in selenium test case using firefox on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, browsers

I am trying to automate a webpage using Single Sign-On. When you try to access the web page it redirects you to different page of Identity Provider, where it asks you for Username and Password inside HTTP Basic Auth popup. After successful authentication, it will redirect you back to originally requested page. Now I am trying to automate this using selenium web driver version 2.45.0. I am first switching to the alert box and then using Robot and Clipboard to do Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v the credentials. The test case works fine on my laptop, where Browser pops up, credentials are keyed in and final page appears after authentication.

When I am trying to run the same code on a linux host command line using Maven after setting DISPLAY=:99 environment variable (headless mode), it is getting stuck. The screenshot statements put to capture the state are displaying blank window. Any idea what can go wrong?

Relevant code snippet:

```
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.sendKeys(username);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        StringSelection pass = new StringSelection(pwd);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pass, null);

        if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS")) {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        } else {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        }
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("/tmp/screenshot2.png"));
        alert.accept();
```

Comment: Is there any JavaScript on your pages? If not you could test on HTTP/REST level instead, e.g., using REST-assured. That's obviously not a solution, but we have used this as a workaround when fixing a problem was too time-consuming.

Comment: Yup, we have javascript and css files on the page.

Comment: Are black screenshots from command-line happening only in this scenario? And are we talking about screenshots taken by Selenium for the browser or taken some other way?

Comment: Yes, seems like alert box is not getting displayed or not getting captured. Yes, taking screenshots by selenium. Updated that code as well in question just now.

Comment: @Krishna, Is that copy & paste is only option to use? Can't we directly enter proper credentials in pop-up itself?

Comment: @NarendraC I am listening, please let me know what you have in mind.

Comment: I mean its fine if we could enter credentials straight forward and mov ahead instead of copy & paste??

Comment: @NarendraC Can we access alert popup with xpath or element id?

Comment: yes, of-course. Thats why I am suggesting you to leave copy & paste. It really looks simple but not actually when you go to automate that > Personal view. Try snippet I shared in Answer!

Comment: are you able to find the workaround to enter the credential in headless? if so can you let us know ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your attention to this post. I finally found the problem when one of my colleague suggested to use VNC to see what's actually going on the linux machine.

For debugging, we need to install "x11vnc" package on the system where tests is being run and then connect to the system using VNC Viewer on a Remote Host.

On target system, run "x11vnc -passwd secret -display :99" and connect to the target with ip_address:5900 (5900 is default port). Soon you will see firefox starting in poor resolution :)

Note: "secret" value to -passwd option can be replaced with any value of your choice. You need to enter this password when prompted by your vnc client.

In my case, I found out that basic authentication pop-up was displayed more different and the tab was sending focus to Google Search text box. Hence the password was getting entered at wrong place.

I think this is valuable technique to find out what's going wrong on your linux box, which doesn't support GUI or GNOME.

[image: How Firefox 22 displays popup on Linux]

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending the credentials in the "Authorization" header using a special URL format like this:

[protocol][user:password]@[domain_name]

You can copy your homepage url and insert user:password@ after the //

For example:
https://user:password@www.example.com

Comment: @lauda This doesn't work coz the authentication page is different from the requested page.

Comment: @TESTasy that's not a link, that's an example to supply basic auth credentials as part of URL.

Comment: Well I guess it's my mistake then... But again this makes it not a good asnwer. There should be proper reasoning to explain the example and why @lauda thinks this will solve the problem.

Comment: If this can work for the other authentication page you could try to add these credentials for that page and when the tests is starting to visit that page first and after that to go to the page you need, homepage or any page.

Comment: @lauda that doesn't work coz the page it is redirecting to isn't static/constant. Also how do you provide basic auth details for a webpage that isn't even loaded yet?

Answer (score 0):

#### Update 2

**Issue: the page it is redirecting to isn't static/constant and you don't know exactly what IdP Random Page coz it will be based on server config**

Suggestion

1. Setting up same account (username/password) for all redirect pages
2. Build list of URL (e.g. https: //user:password@**redirectPage1**/originalURL=yoursite)
3. Create a test for each redirectPage

   - redirectPage1 --> verify A
   - redirectPage2 --> verify B
   - ...

#### Update 1

**I just see the your reply to @lauda that the redirected site/page is not static.**

Assume there are **3 pages (page1, page2, page3)** in redirection list, I think you should know the condition to redirect to each page. So you can base on this rule to build a *URL1 that always redirect to page1, and so on URL2 for page2, URL3 for page3*.

If my assume works then

1. Login Identity Provider site using @lauda comment: https://user:password@www.example.com
2. Go to your home page
3. Continue your script

#### Original

Workaround

1. Go to Identity Provider (redirect) site (use redirection link)
2. Then login as @lauda's comment https://user:password@www.example.com
3. Go to your home page
4. Continue your script

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the first requested page redirects you to the Identity Provider page, putting the requested page as OriginalUrl parameter in the end of URL in address bar/get request. And after successful authentication, the IdP redirects you to Original URL which is part of the redirection URL. So I can't go to IdP directly.

Comment: What happens if you use the link that included the requested page as parameter in the end of URL (go to your home page, copy URL after redirection). Does it give the same behavior ? If yes, then you can replace that link at #1 step above.

Comment: @KrishnaPandey One trick is to use proxy that will replace redirect URL on the fly.

Comment: @Krishna Pandey: I just update the answer after seeing your reply to lauda "the page it is redirecting to isn't static/constant"

Comment: So there is Page1, IdP Random Page, Page1. 
1. So providing username, password to Page1 won't work. 2. You don't know exactly what IdP Random Page coz it will be based on server config, so you can't hardcode it.

Comment: so when you access your home page, it will redirect to Random page and it ask you to provide authentication info ? How about setting up same account (username/password) for all redirect pages, then we build list of URL (e.g. https ://user:password@redirectPage1/originalURL=yoursite)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues :

1. Robot class is taking real screen parameter and worked on that. In headless browser there is no alert is available so it would stuck when robot try to access that alert or pop up window. Also your implicit wait is more so you feels it is stuck. But wait until your implicit wait completed. After that it will throws error.
2. In Headless browser Selenium can not able take screenshot of what your are accessing. [Reference](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1361)

Actually any different kind of code will not helps you. Because any API require displayed component or screen for screenshots.

**Solution :** 
I would suggest that Try to run with real browser. Headless is better when there are not pop up windows and Ajax type calls.

Comment: That code works with real browser as mentioned in question itself.

Comment: But for headless it can't be.

Comment: Incidentally, if you need a headless browser that *can* take screenshots, look into PhantomJS.

Comment: I think this question is based on selenium and headless browser. So my answer context in only within that. If phantomJS can help the questioner then its great.

Comment: @Sagar007 I just answered my question, please take a look. It's lifesaving when debugging blind-folded.

Comment: @KrishnaPandey If this solves your problems then great. Nice work. We all have some new technique to learn.

Answer (score 0):

- Solution 1:- **Go with the straight forward process as do manually:**

  For that we need to maintain proper flow while working with main window and pop-up. Refer below snippet, Consider main window = paren & pop-up window = child

  ```
  Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
  Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();

  String parent = it.next();
  String child = it.next();

  driver.switchTo().window(child);
  //perform actions on child window

  driver.close(); // only for child wondow


  driver.switchTo().window(parent);
  //perform actions on parent window

  driver.quit(); // After execution of main thread and for parent window
  ```
- Solution 2:- **Work around to handle pop-up -**

If you are really looking to have some way to implement, You can use "*Java AWT Robot class*" to handle the scenario. using this class you can perform mouse actions on basis of screen coordinates or you can use AutoIT to automate this process for handling windows popup

Update us if you have queries or issue resolved.

Comment: @Krishna - You have not find any answer useful?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The tab before pasting password using clipboard was sending focus to Google Search textbox of Firefox. I was able to debug that using VNC. See my answer for how to setup that.

Comment: forgot to add I am yet to try the snippet above, will update once I do.

Comment: Hope it helps you

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work.

Comment: Still working at my end without any change. I will suggest you to crosscheck once for you are working with each window appropriately.